# Blocking UDP packets with a length of 4

Tags: linux, iptables, ddos

My server is being flooded with UDP packets with a length of 4 (header is 32 bytes).

```
04:56:26.844797 IP 108.241.236.114.47034 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.844831 IP 5.2.81.91.41240 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.844866 IP 210.87.250.55.40919 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.844900 IP 94.73.142.23.55904 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.844940 IP 122.146.80.27.53779 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.844970 IP 151.164.8.177.57392 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845003 IP 107.199.209.29.58712 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845042 IP 109.69.210.61.55743 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845075 IP 174.142.83.201.57903 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845112 IP 109.86.103.4.59078 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845143 IP 195.73.208.205.48309 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845179 IP 24.227.213.112.47999 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845232 IP 203.126.92.200.44085 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845266 IP 155.223.130.101.41779 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845280 IP 207.71.48.115.47343 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845297 IP 173.45.246.116.56800 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845324 IP 5.19.255.191.56223 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845359 IP 91.121.45.106.41200 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845393 IP 89.135.59.191.43939 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845423 IP 208.125.243.239.46874 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845457 IP 193.61.128.69.42921 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845494 IP 210.253.139.44.58710 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845533 IP 24.242.179.242.53563 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845561 IP 110.50.110.211.54071 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845581 IP 217.14.193.97.49223 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845628 IP 31.210.67.1.52423 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
04:56:26.845644 IP 178.33.119.122.51731 > 185.5.173.249.14522: UDP, length 4
```

I already have a rule to block this, but it doesn't appear to work, the packets still come in.

```
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p udp -m length --length 4 -j DROP
```

The header length is 32, then destination length 4. I'm trying to block on length 4 only.

How can I effectively block these attack packets?

Comment: I understand that English might not be your primary language, but your question is not clear at all.

Comment: sorry i'm bad english dude, but i got attack my server udp length 4, you can help me how to block that truely

Comment: It depends how the attack is hurting you. For example, if the attack is hurting you by consuming the bandwidth on the link to the machine, blocking them *at the machine* won't help, they've already consumed the bandwidth. Back up and tell us about your *problem* and then we can figure out how to solve it.

Comment: I think your issue may be your length.. And the headers are not 32 bytes unless there are IP options being set.  IP headers are 20 bytes (barring options) and the UDP header is -always- 8 bytes.  Answer to follow

Comment: This might be a better fit in the Security forum

Answer (score 9):

To solve this problem you need to understand a few facts:

- The IPTables Length module measures against the total length of the packet.
- The UDP header is always 8 bytes in length.
- The IP header is typically 20 bytes but can be longer.

With that knowledge here is an example that will block UDP packets with a data payload less than 4 bytes where there are no IP options:

`iptables -A PREROUTING -p udp -m length --length 28:32 -j DROP`

You could also, of course, use `--length 0:32` since those would also be invalid packets; you can't ever have a legal UDP packet with a total size less than 28 bytes.  In fact, even at 28 bytes it is highly anomalous since that would be sending a datagram...with no data.

Hope this helps.

Comment: but i need lenght 32 for my streaming, so maybe i need u32 lenght udp 32
 iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp -m length --length 6:32 -m u32 --u32 "0x6&0xff=0x11&&0x0>>0x16&0x3c@0x2&0xff=0x8" -j DROP


please check in, for my rule dude, this rule not really work for payload lenght 32

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a Distributed Denial of Service (DDoS) attack, and if it's saturating the inbound network connection to your edge (either a router, or a server), then no amount of firewalling inside your network will fix this, as the link *to* you is already saturated.

The recommended method of DDoS mitigation is to ask your ISP to filter this traffic out before it reaches your network.

In the long term, it might be worth negotiating with a DDoS mitigation consultant to allow you to get a ["clean pipe"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Clean_pipes) connection to the internet. (Usually works by tunneling your traffic through a GRE tunnel to a DDoS mitigation intermediary, who have the upstream connectivity to handle an attack, and filter out the attack traffic, before routing to you).